# Save in database didn't work ?! (VB.NET | OLE)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I used the following code to save what the user editing , the code don't give me any error code , but in the same time it don't do any thing , the data still without any new changes :

```
 Dim a As String
        a = comb3.Text & "/" & comb2.Text & "/" & comb1.Text
        Dim SavInto As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim ConStr As String = _
           "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" & _
          Application.StartupPath & "\base.mdb"
        Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr)
        Conn.Open()
        SavInto.Connection = Conn
        SavInto.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        SavInto.CommandText = "UPDATE tb SET Tasalsol = '" & _
       Trim(frm.tx1.Text) & _
           "' , anomber = '" & Trim(frm.TextBox2.Text) & _
         "' , nam= '" & Trim(frm.tx3.Text) & _
        "' , rotba= '" & Trim(frm.tx4.Text) & _
          "' , spesh= '" & Trim(frm.tx5.Text) & _
         "' , lastvstart= '" & a & _
           "'  WHERE Notes ='" & Trim(frm.tx8.Text) & "'"

        SavInto.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()

        With frm
            .tx1.Text = Me.tx1.Text
            .TextBox2.Text = Me.tx2.Text
            .tx3.Text = Me.tx3.Text
            .tx4.Text = Me.tx4.Text
            .tx5.Text = Me.tx5.Text
            .tx6.Text = a
            .tx8.Text = Me.tx8.Text

        End With
        frm.Show()
        Me.Close()
```

I wrote the whole code , **so what is the wrong exactly**  ?! and thank you

**Note**:There is some columns that may have many same data in its cells .

Comment: SQL Injection attacks are right behind the door. Don't concatenate string values like that to create a query. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Does your SQL work correctly when you run it directly in the database? If you step into your code and stop right after CommandText is set, you can see the SQL being sent. Copy that and run it in the database and verify that it works correctly.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the `WHERE` clause evaluates to false and therefore, no row is updated.

Comment: I know you didn't ask for a critique, but if I was looking at this code in the code review, I'd suggest giving your variables more descriptive names than "a", naming your textboxes something meaningful (prefer txtUsername and txtDescription over tx1 and comb3), moving your connection string into the config file instead of hard-coding it, and using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from Mehrdad's *very* wise advice about using a parameterised query instead, your WHERE clause looks very odd. Are you really sure you want to be using a "notes" field to determine which row to update? And is `tx8` an editable field? Why are you trimming it? It seems very unlikely that the best way of finding the row to update is via a field called "notes" which appears to be plain text which might require trimming.

It would be *much* better to use the ID of the row (or rows) in question to update it.

Note that you're not looking at the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` - I suspect it's returning 0, to indicate that it's not updated any rows. You should be checking that.

Also you should be using `Using` statements for both the connection and the command, so that they will be disposed appropriately even an exception is thrown.

Just to reiterate though: please, *please* use parameterised queries instead of embedding values in SQL. Queries like that make DBAs cry.

Comment: Thank you mr.Jon , In fact I feel that your answer is very useful , but I really crashed because there is so many mistakes in the code , so can you give me some example about how can I edit it ?

Comment: @Eias.N: I'm afraid I don't have any examples to hand - but I suspect you could search for some. I suggest you concentrate on one aspect at a time.